# how to disable tabs' scroll of jquery-easyui

Tags: jquery-easyui

Browser:IE

When i click the tabs of jquery-easyui, there always scrolling on the right side.
jquery-easyui doesn't provide a proper method to solve this problem.
Please give some advise(s), thank you ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
[Here is the soluction source](https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=7113d1ed-b8c9-492a-acdf-387b4139b49e#gsc.tab=0)

The theory is override the jquery-easyui css via declare local css

here is the code snippet from the link previously mentioned.

```
<style type="text/css">

/* Remove the right scroll bar easyui tabs */

#tabs .tabs-panels>.panel>.panel-body {

overflow: hidden;

}

</style>
```